# Are there differences between ics files for Apple and MIcrosoft?

Tags: icalendar

I am creating an html form that accepts calendar event inputs, and returns an ics file. Are there any parameters of an ics file that are different between Apple and Microsoft devices?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack.

No, no platform specific parameters are required to be provided to be read by an external platform.   Of course if you mean parameters to URL, you can offer what you want - they become part of the URL for that ics calendar feed.

If you producing an ics file then you should familiarise yourself with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545 or https://icalendar.org/RFC-Specifications/iCalendar-RFC-5545/.   The RFC 5545 ics specification is platform agnostic. It allows for private non-standard properties which can be (usually are) platform specific See

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.8.2
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Calendar_extensions

Apple of course has the unofficial uri webcal.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal.    It is not necessary to offer that.  Apple does handle the standard http/s protocol with Mime type text/calendar and suffix .ics.